# Amount of Bleeding from Wounded Lungs

Tags: lungs, bleeding, internal-bleeding, gunshot-wounds

For a game, I need at least a vague estimate on how much the lungs will bleed. One person mentioned that a deer shot through both lungs with a hunting rifle would be stopped by the bleeding within 10 to 15 minutes.

Does anyone have an estimate on bleeding in human lungs? In general, I'd hope to have an extreme case, and a mild case for comparison, as then I can tweak the numbers to count for that unpredictable variance that comes with injury.

Comment: Somewhere between minutes and days. Honestly, there are so many variables that almost any numbers you pluck out of thin air will be credible. Suffice it to say that a weapon of large caliber, high muzzle velocity, and/or use of ammunition designed to maximize injury will produce greater injury and more rapid death in most cases. For example, surviving a hunting rifle shot to the lungs is unlikely, but even a .22 pistol can be equally lethal if it happens to hit a major vessel.

Comment: It's true that it is very hard to estimate. Thank you for your input, I will make a reasonable guess and see how it goes.